# Generic Way of Capturing Page Title, Control labels

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, web-applications, dom-events

One of our customers has a new requirement to dynamically capture the page/screen title and the labels of all the controls(textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, normal buttons,link,images,menu/menu items) on the page the users interacts with and then push them to an excel file.

If customer navigates/opens a page A and sets a value in the textbox Name = John , enables the checkboxChBox/radio button Rbutton and then finally clicks save/submit button, then the following output is being expected. User Action and Results being the first 2 columns of the Excel file.

```
     **User Action**                               **Result**

      Open Page/Screen A                            Page/Screen A is displayed
      Set textbox Name = John                       Field Name is set successfully
      Set  ChBox = true                             ChBox is enabled successfully
      Set Rbutton = true                            Rbutton is enabled successfully
      Click Submit button                           Page B is displayed
```

Just wondering if it is possible to accomplish this and generic way of capturing the user interactions of any page.

Comment: Hi Antony. The web application was delivered to the customer, but the customer wanted some kind of enhancement/ provision with in the web application to generate such an excel file with the above 2 columns

Comment: What your customer is asking is somewhat possible but it would be a PITA to implement. Note that you must track every user action in client side and some actions on server side as well, and probably saving all this info in a database and provide a report in Excel format.

Comment: are they wanting to be able to download a csv/excel file of records in a table?

Comment: Hi Luiggi and Antony. Thanks for the reply. Yes the customer wants to download an excel file, as soon as he stops interacting with application with the expected 2 columns and the text beneath these columns based on the type of interaction/event with the application

Comment: Well, your customer is insane. IMO I would drop this requirement because the high cost of development and maintenance and the app performance  will go down to the other side of the world (yes, irony but you get the idea).

Comment: Hi Luiggi, Thanks a lot for the reply.yes personally i fully agree with what you suggested, but i do not possess authority to turn down client's requirement. instead i shall get pushed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea : you could listen all events (with jquery, for example), and then post an ajax request for each 'interesting' event (you have to filter...), store it in a database, and then add an 'export' function in csv or excel format.

Maybe some performance issues, it depends on the amount of pages, events and users...

The idea to use class name to filter is good, thanks to Hasan Iqbal Anik.

Comment: Hi Thierry, thanks a lot the reply. Could you elaborate it a little more. i haven't done this in the past. By the way, the customer does not want the output to go into the database and from there on, export to excel. what he wants is to create a switch kind of thing to turn on the functionality/feature which can trace and export to an excel file directly on the client machine.

Comment: You can't create a file on the client machine. For security reasons, you can't have access to the file system.

Comment: i am sorry, when I say client machine, i mean the machine from which we use browser to interact with the application. sorry, it was not customer's machine

Comment: I also speak about this machine... A web application, displayed in a browser, can't access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have access to writing files in hard drive. However you can capture the data, make a model and then store it in the server using ajax calls.

Some ideas:

1. Use a layout or master page that is rendered throughout the application views.
2. Give same class name for all the page labels, buttons, checkboxes and anything you need to store information about.
3. Use some jquery magic in the master/layout page to get the values of those elements and make an array.
4. Send that array through ajax call to the server.

Now you can get tons of examples of how to get element values using jquery. I'm saving you from giving all that. Hope that helps...  :D

//edit: i'm trying to extend my answer as per steve requested.

```
<form action="someAction" id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" class="Name">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" class="ChBox"/>Click this box
RButton: <input class="Rbutton" type="radio" />
Submit: <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now some jquery:

```
$(function() {
     $(".submit").click(function(){
var dataToSend = new Object();
dataToSend.pageUrl = window.location.pathname + " is displayed";
if ($(".Name").val().length > 0) {
dataToSend.Name = "Field Name is set successfully";
}
else {
dataToSend.Name = "Field Name is empty";
}
if($(".ChBox").is(':checked')){dataToSend.ChBox = "ChBox is enabled successfully";}
else{dataToSend.ChBox = "ChBox is not enabled";}
if($(".Rbutton").is(':checked')){dataToSend.Rbutton = "Rbutton is enabled successfully";}
else{dataToSend.Rbutton = "Rbutton is not checked";}
dataToSend.Submit = $("#myForm").attr['action'] + " is displayed";
});


//now send it to the server via ajax

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "your server action url that would make excel file with these data",
 data: dataToSend,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(msg) {
//do as you wish
 }
});

    });
```

Comment: Hi Hasan, thanks a lot the reply. Could you elaborate it a little more. i haven't done this in the past. By the way, the customer does not want the ouput to go into the database and from there on, export to excel. what he wants is to create a switch kind of thing to turn on the functionality/feature which can trace and export to an excel file directly on the client machine.